# Python multicore CSV short program, advice/help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm a hobby coder started with AHK, then some java and now I try to learn Python. *I have searched and found some tips but I have yet not been able to implement it into my own code.*
Hopefully someone here can help me, it's a very short program.
I'm using  .txt csv database with ";" as a separator.
DATABASE EXAMPLE:

Which color is normally a cat?;Black

How tall was the longest man on earth?;272 cm

Is the earth round?;Yes

The database now consists of 20.000 lines which makes the program "to slow", only using 25% CPU (1 core).

If I can make it use all 4 cores (100%) I guess it would perform the task alot faster. The task is basically to compare the CLIPBOARD with the database and if there is a match, it should give me an answer as a return. Perhaps also I can separate the database into 4 pieces?

The code right now looks like this! Not more then **65** lines and its doing its job (but to slow). Advice on how I can make this process into multi core needed.

```
    import time
    import pyperclip as pp
    import pandas as pd
    import pymsgbox as pmb
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    import numpy


    ratio_threshold = 90
    fall_back_time = 1
    db_file_path = 'database.txt'
    db_separator = ';'
    db_encoding = 'latin-1'

    def load_db():
        while True:
            try:
                # Read and create database
                db = pd.read_csv(db_file_path, sep=db_separator, encoding=db_encoding)
                db = db.drop_duplicates()
                return db
            except:
                print("Error in load_db(). Will sleep for %i seconds..." % fall_back_time)
        time.sleep(fall_back_time)


    def top_answers(db, question):
        db['ratio'] = db['question'].apply(lambda q: fuzz.ratio(q, question))
        db_sorted = db.sort_values(by='ratio', ascending=False)
        db_sorted = db_sorted[db_sorted['ratio'] >= ratio_threshold]
        return db_sorted


    def write_txt(top):
        result = top.apply(lambda row: "%s" % (row['answer']), axis=1).tolist()
        result = '\n'.join(result)
        fileHandle = open("svar.txt", "w")
        fileHandle.write(result)
        fileHandle.close()
        pp.copy("")


    def main():
        try:
            db = load_db()
            last_db_reload = time.time()

            while True:
                # Get contents of clipboard
                question = pp.paste()

                # Rank answer
                top = top_answers(db, question)

                # If answer was found, show results
                if len(top) > 0:
                    write_txt(top)
                time.sleep(fall_back_time)
        except:
            print("Error in main(). Will sleep for %i seconds..." % fall_back_time)
            time.sleep(fall_back_time)


   if name == 'main':
       main()'
```

Comment: You are aware that the argument to `time.sleep()` is in seconds (as opposed to milliseconds in many other languages)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip! Can change it to 0.01 instead of 1. Will speed up the process a little bit of course but sadly - not enough.

Right now it can take up to 10 seconds to retrieve a "answer" from a question of the 20.000 rows.

Still need a multi-core solution to make it very fast.

Comment: I think you should focus on finding a better algorithm (speeding up the constant time needed for each item in the database) and [pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruning_%28decision_trees%29) (finding a quick way to skip parts of the database so you don't need to run the expensive fuzzy algorithm at all, for example if the db item does not contain any of the words from your search query).

Answer (score 0):

If you could divide the db into four equally large you could process them in parallel like this:

```
import time
import pyperclip as pp
import pandas as pd
import pymsgbox as pmb
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import numpy
import threading

ratio_threshold = 90
fall_back_time = 1
db_file_path = 'database.txt'
db_separator = ';'
db_encoding = 'latin-1'


def worker(thread_id, question):
    thread_id = str(thread_id)
    db = pd.read_csv(db_file_path + thread_id, sep=db_separator,    encoding=db_encoding)
    db = db.drop_duplicates()
    db['ratio'] = db['question'].apply(lambda q: fuzz.ratio(q, question))
    db_sorted = db.sort_values(by='ratio', ascending=False)
    db_sorted = db_sorted[db_sorted['ratio'] >= ratio_threshold]
    top = db_sorted
    result = top.apply(lambda row: "%s" % (row['answer']), axis=1).tolist()
    result = '\n'.join(result)
    fileHandle = open("svar" + thread_id + ".txt", "w")
    fileHandle.write(result)
    fileHandle.close()
    pp.copy("")
    return


def main():
    question = pp.paste()
    for i in range(1, 4):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i, question))
        t.start()
        t.join()


if name == 'main':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with multiprocessing:

```
import time
import pyperclip as pp
import pandas as pd
#import pymsgbox as pmb
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import numpy as np

# pathos uses better pickle to tranfer more complicated objects
from pathos.multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import reduce

import sys
import os
from contextlib import closing

ratio_threshold = 70
fall_back_time = 1
db_file_path = 'database.txt'
db_separator = ';'
db_encoding = 'latin-1'

chunked_db = []
NUM_PROCESSES = os.cpu_count()

def load_db():
    while True:
        try:
            # Read and create database
            db = pd.read_csv(db_file_path, sep=db_separator, encoding=db_encoding)
            db.columns = ['question', 'answer']
            #db = db.drop_duplicates() # i drop it for experiment
            break
        except:
            print("Error in load_db(). Will sleep for %i seconds..." % fall_back_time)
    time.sleep(fall_back_time)
    # split database into equal chunks:
    # (if you have a lot of RAM, otherwise you 
    # need to compute ranges in db, something like
    # chunk_size = len(db)//NUM_PROCESSES
    # ranges[i] = (i*chunk_size, (i+1)*cjunk_size)
    # and pass ranges in original db to processes
    chunked_db = np.split(db, [NUM_PROCESSES], axis=0)
    return chunked_db




def top_answers_multiprocessed(question, chunked_db):

    # on unix, python uses 'fork' mode by default
    # so the process has 'copy-on-change' access to all global variables
    # i.e. if process will change something in db, it will be copied to it
    # with a lot of overhead
    # Unfortunately, I'fe heard that on Windows only 'spawn' mode with full 
    # copy of everything is used

    # Process pipeline uses pickle, it's quite slow.
    # so on small database you may not have benefit from multiprocessing
    # If you are going to transfer big objects in or out, look
    # in the direction of multiprocessing.Array

    # this solution is not fully efficient,
    # as pool is recreated each time

    # You can create daemon processes which will monitor
    # Queue for incoming questions, but it's harder to implement
    def top_answers(idx):
        # question is in the scope of parent function, 
        chunked_db[idx]['ratio'] = chunked_db[idx]['question'].apply(lambda q: fuzz.ratio(q, question))
        db_sorted = chunked_db[idx].sort_values(by='ratio', ascending=False)
        db_sorted = db_sorted[db_sorted['ratio'] >= ratio_threshold]
        return db_sorted



    with closing(Pool(processes=NUM_PROCESSES)) as pool:
        # chunked_db is a list of databases
        # they are in global scope, we send only index beacause
        # all the data set is pickled
        num_chunks = len(chunked_db)
        # apply function top_answers across generator range(num_chunks)
        res = pool.imap_unordered(top_answers, range(num_chunks))
        res = list(res) 
        # now res is list of dataframes, let's join it
        res_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='ratio'), res)
    return res_final





def write_txt(top):
    result = top.apply(lambda row: "%s" % (row['answer']), axis=1).tolist()
    result = '\n'.join(result)
    fileHandle = open("svar.txt", "w")
    fileHandle.write(result)
    fileHandle.close()
    pp.copy("")


def mainfunc():
   global chunked_db
   chunked_db = load_db()
   last_db_reload = time.time()
   print('db loaded')

   last_clip = ""
   while True:
       # Get contents of clipboard
       try:
           new_clip = pp.paste()
       except:
           continue

       if (new_clip != last_clip) and (len(new_clip)> 0):
           print(new_clip)
           last_clip = new_clip

           question = new_clip.strip()
       else:
           continue


       # Rank answer
       top = top_answers_multiprocessed(question, chunked_db)

       # If answer was found, show results
       if len(top) > 0:
            #write_txt(top)
            print(top)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainfunc()
```